# jsDoc static folder not copied to output folder

Tags: documentation, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I have this jsdoc config file, including a folder of images within the tutorials
folder (as suggested by https://jsdoc.app/about-tutorials)

```
{
    "source": {
        "include": ["README.md", "src"],
        "includePattern": ".js$"
    },
    "plugins": ["plugins/markdown"],
    "opts": {
        "readme": "./README.md",
        "destination": "./docs/",
        "tutorials": "./tutorials",
        "templates": {
            "default": {
                "staticFiles": {
                    "include": ["./tutorials/static"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The repo has this layout

```
jsdoc.json (above)
src/
    <two test files>
docs/ (jsdoc's output)
tutorials/
    <two markdown files>
    static/
        <images>
package.json
    one script: rm -rf docs/* && jsdoc -c jsdoc.json --verbose
```

This creates docs/ which has the src & tutorials nicely documented:

```
Model.html              scripts
Model.js.html           styles
fonts                   tutorial-GettingStarted.html
index.html              tutorial-JavaScript.html
module-src_utils.html   utils.js.html
```

BUT without the static/ folder being copied over!

What am I doing wrong?! Thanks.

Note: [Adding static files to JSDoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30058201/adding-static-files-to-jsdoc) is similar but with a much earlier syntax.